# Can I capture Windows Mobile PIE keyboard events?

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-mobile, key-events

Anyone know of a way to capture keyboard events (keyup / keydown) in Portable IE under Window mobile? I noticed that key events are not supported in JS, and would like to come up with a solution that works without any client side additions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Without* any client side additions?

As per [IEMobile Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/iemobile/archive/2006/04/06/570375.aspx),  the only way for that would be wait for the next release :(